# Case insensitive user input strings

Tags: python, user-input, case-insensitive

Which function to use for making user input strings case insensitive?

```
correctAnswer = "London"

userGuess = input("What is the capital of  Great Britain?: ")

if userGuess == "London":
    print("Correct!")
else:
    print("Wrong")
```

I have tried the following functions after the string:

```
.lower()
.capitalize()
.casefold()
```

The output is still 'wrong' although the answer should be correct when input is: 
- london 
- lOndoN 
- loNDON

And so on..

Comment: You have to change both of them to the same case: `if userGuess.lower() == "London".lower():` OR use `title` for example: `if userGuess.title() == "London":`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your string comparison, the correct answer itself had the first letter capitalized.

```
correctAnswer = "london"

userGuess = input("What is the capital of  Great Britain?: ").lower()

if userGuess == correctAnswer:
    print("Correct!")
else:
    print("Wrong")
```

Comment: More clear (but less optimal) would probably be `if userGuess.lower() == correctAnswer.lower()`

Answer (score 2):

I think that your problem is that `correctAnswer` is not lowercase, but [titled](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=title()#str.title). Python doesn't do case insensitivity, but you can apply the same function to the correct answer and userGuess to compare them.

Your options are:

1. Apply `.lower()` to `correctAnswer`
2. Change `correctAnswer` to `correctAnswer = "london"` and use `userGuess.lower()`
3. use `userGuess.title()` and `correctAnswer = "London"`

Answer (score 0):

When comparing case-insensitive strings, it is common practice to compare all with lower case.
In fact, in your program, there is no point of comparing the input with `London` (with capital "l"), that's why you should compare with `london` instead.
The way you can compare it is as follows:

```
correct_answer = "london"
userGuess = input("What is the capital of  Great Britain?: ")
if userGuess.lower() == correct_answer:
    print("Correct!")
else:
    print("Wrong")
```

**NOTE**

I used `lower()` method in the if statement not in the input statement. This is better so you can keep the user's input as is, maybe you'll use it in another way later.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
correctAnswer = "London"

userGuess = input("What is the capital of  Great Britain?: ")
userGuess = userGuess.capitalize()
#print(userGuess)

if userGuess == correctAnswer:
    print("Correct!")
else:
    print("Wrong")
```

**capitalize()** method converts the first character of a string to capital (uppercase) letter.