# No matter what I enter for this code, it tells me my bill is $0

Tags: python

I've been working on this code for the Udemy class, 100 days of code and no matter what I enter it tells me my bill is $0 and I can't figure out why.

```
print("Welcome to Python Pizza Deliveries!")
size = input("What size pizza do you want? S, M, or L ")
add_pepperoni = input("Do you want pepperoni? Y or N ")
extra_cheese = input("Do you want extra cheese? Y or N ")

bill = 0;

if size == "S":
    bill += 15
elif size == "M":
    bill += 20
elif size == "L":
    bill += 25
if add_pepperoni == "Y":
    if size == "S":
        bill += 2
    else:
        bill += 3
if extra_cheese == "Y":
    bill += 1

print(f"Your final bill is ${bill}")
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce, I get `Your final bill is $18` for `S` `Y` `Y`.

Comment: Are you making sure to type capital letters when you answer the questions? This code only works when the user types capitals. See [Case insensitive user input strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56708668/354577), for example.

Answer (score 0):

I typed `L N N` and it works just fine as you expected(25$). What input are you giving? Btw, if you added any space before or after the match it won't give proper output. You may find the strip() method useful in this case. It returns a new string with the spaces trimmed from either side (if any). Here's how you do it:

```
size = input("What size pizza do you want? S, M, or L ").strip()
```

Comment: This should likely be a comment, not an answer. The `strip()` thing is a blind guess.